# h1 and nav on the same line

Tags: html, css

I searched Stack overflow and google and tried all the suggestions to getting my h1 and nav on the same line. I tried inline, inline-block, setting the header itself to 100%. It's just not aligning. On top of that my li posted backwards when I set it to float left so the home that was on the top of the list is now on the outer end instead of the beginning. here's my code

```css
  .header{
        background-color: #00001a;
        height: 40px;
        width: 100%;
       }
    
        ul{
         list-style-type: none;
        }
    
        .header h1{
         float: left;
         color: #ffffff;
         font-size: 15px;
         display: inline-block;
        }
    
       .nav li{
        float: right;
        display: inline-block;
        color: #ffffff;
       }
```

```html
<div class="header">
       <div class="nav">
        <h1>EaTogeter</h1>
        <ul>
         <li>home</li>
         <li>About</li>
         <li>Couples</li>
         <li>family</li>
        </ul> 
        </div>
       </div>
        <div class="Maincontent">
          <div class="container">
          <h2>Try It</h2
          <p>Today's Try It Recipe!<p>
         </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: Your `<h2>` isn't closed: you have `</h2>`

Comment: I've edited it to be a snippet and closed the `<h2>` and it looks alright to me, so maybe that's all it is.

Answer (score 5):

`display: flex; justify-content: space-between;` will put them on the same line and separate them with the available space.

```css
.header {
  background-color: #00001a;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
 
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.header h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.nav li {
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="nav">
    <h1>EaTogeter</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Couples</li>
      <li>family</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @k97513 the text is white.

Comment: I'd choose this method because floats are a world of pain and [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) has a LOT of support.

Answer (score 0):

Put the heading and the navigation in their own containers. Float one left, the other right, and make sure to clear them afterwards.

```css
header {
    background-color: #00001a;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="left">
        <h1>
        EaTogether
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Couples</li>
            <li>Family</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</header>
```

Note: I've changed "Togeter" to "Together", assuming it was a typo.

Comment: If I had to guess why this would have been downvoted, it might be the reliance on extraneous markup?

Comment: It's unfortunate that all we can do is guess. Also, I don't believe my snippet would run without the extraneous markup, but oh well.

Comment: I just posted an answer that uses less markup. You could easily not wrap the `h1` or the `ul` in your example and instead apply the classes directly to the elements they wrap. The wrappers could be justified though if there was additional content/markup that needed to be grouped. As a side note, do you ever use a clearfix instead of a clearing DIV?

Comment: "You didn't use the least amount of markup possible" is not grounds for a downvote and I'm note sure what you're getting at, to be perfectly honest. I never said "An answer with less markup is not possible", so I'm glad you wrote one with less markup, but that has no relation to this. But regardless, it's a single downvote. This discussion in itself is more extraneous than any markup at all.

Comment: That is true. I was just following up on my initial comment and observation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want this thing but I just gave a try,

**For this, set float:right to ul element and not on li elements.
Since you want to align h1 and li content set line-height to 0.5 for ul element**

please check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hz0104mp/

```
<div class="header">
       <div class="nav">
        <h1>EaTogeter</h1>
        <ul>
         <li>home</li>
         <li>About</li>
         <li>Couples</li>
         <li>family</li>
        </ul>   
        </div>
       </div>
        <div class="Maincontent">
          <div class="container">
          <h2>Try It</h2>
          <p>Today's Try It Recipe!<p>
         </div>
       </div>


.header{
        background-color: #00001a;
        height: 40px;
        width: 100%;
       }

        ul{
         list-style-type: none;
        }

        .header h1{
         color: #ffffff;
         font-size: 15px;
         display: inline-block;
        }

       .nav ul{
          float:right;
          line-height:0.5;
        }

       .nav li{
        display: inline-block;
        color: #ffffff;
       }
```

Comment: Answers should have some sort of explanation. As it stands, your answer is currently a game of spot-the-difference.

Comment: The downvote was because of the exact reason I said. Because you fixed it, I removed the downvote. (Which, as a sidebar, is why it's important to always comment on an answer that you downvote. Unfortunately the person who downvoted my answer did not do the same :/ )

Comment: Thanks Santi for the feedback. Will take care from now onwards. Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

I like the `flexbox` method mentioned by **@Michael Coker** but here's a solution using floats as the OP attempted to do.

You were on the right track but might have been applying some of your CSS to the wrong elements for the wrong reasons.

> On top of that my li posted backwards when I set it to float left so the home that was on the top of the list is now on the outer end instead of the beginning.

The reasons for this are not obvious until you break things down. The reason this happens is because `float: right` is applied to each element separately and in the order they appear in the markup, not as a whole. The browser will float *Home* as far to the right as it can. After that, it will move *About* as far to the right as it can. Rinse and repeat for any other `li`.

I rectified this by floating the `ul` instead of individual `li` and setting those to `display: inline;`. Floating the `li` to the left would also work.

```css
header {
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  height: 40px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #00001a;
}

ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
header h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
header h1,
.nav li {
  line-height: 40px;
}
.nav {
  float: right;
}
.nav li {
  padding: 0 0 0 0.25rem;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<header>
  
    <h1>Eat Together</h1>
  
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Couples</li>
      <li>Family</li>
    </ul>
  
</header>

<main>
  
    <h2>Try It</h2>
    <p>Today's Try It Recipe!<p>
    
</main>
```

Please note that I took a few liberties with your markup to help provide an example of how it can be more semantic and achieved with less markup (along with a few choice styles to make it a little more *"pretty"*).